# Update child values in Firebase when node value is unknown/autogenerated Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a search function in my app that works, and returns values from the DB and populates textviews on my screen. What I want to implement is that if a value for the textview is updated, we can press a save button and the values that were returned from the search are updated under the same db ID.

Here is my database structure:
[image]

And here is the update method I'm trying to implement:

```
func updateRecord(){

    guard let pub: String = searchText.text?.lowercased() else { return }

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("Drinks")


    let query = databaseRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "pub").queryStarting(atValue: pub).queryEnding(atValue: "\(String(describing: pub))\\uf8ff")

    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard snapshot.exists() != false else {

            print("Error, doesn't exist")

            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let signature = "E"


            //adding drink data
            let drink = [
                "pub": self.pubName.text!.lowercased() as String,
                "location": self.pubLocation.text!.lowercased() as String,
                "price": self.price.text!.lowercased() as String,
                "rating": self.rating.text!.lowercased() as String,
                "comment": self.comment.text!.lowercased() as String,
                "signature": signature
            ]
            databaseRef.child(--How do I access this token, for the drink in the picture I need to get "Lzsx_Vv5x5WVFsig-Zl"--).setValue(drink)

            return
        }
    }
}
```

Basically in my db I need to be able to access the autogenerated ID that the data is stored under. I know the method 'updateChildValues' can work, or "setValue" again as I'm storing the info again, but how can I access the ID the data is stored under?

Thanks, E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure since I haven't used Firebase for one year.  But try the following.

```
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
        for drink in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let id = drink.key; print(id)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're dead on, spent a few hours yesterday trying different things & your answer hit the nail on the head. Appreciate the help!